# Append text to part of regex match

Tags: c++, regex, json, string

I need to make some funky json. Basically the format should be

```
"userName:string":"teddyblackk"
```

Notice the string in there. I need to append the data type to the key name, given the normal looking json

```
"userName":"teddyblack"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this. I was thinking that maybe there was someway to take a macth to the regex:

```
"\"[a-zA-Z0-9-_]\"[\s]*:[\s]*\"[a-zA-Z0-9-_]\""  ==> a json string key value pair
```

and take the first half and append a `":string"` into it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the obvious solution would be to parse the JSON, enumerate every key, and build a new JSON with altered key names.  Rather like HTML, regular expressions are probably not the right tool for the job of modifying JSON.

Comment: the library I have to use needs the types in there to parse the json into a map. That's why I need to add the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(?="\s*:)
```

and replace w/ `:string`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/49)

Comment: almost what I need, though if the json should be a int such as "age":40, I'd need it to append ':i32'. Same for maps and lists and  whatever else type for json.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out using your regex. Thanks